# Retrieving first elements of lines

Tags: command-line, vim

I have a text file for which each line looks like:

number, description1, description2,...,

How can I retrieve in a file the numbers only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [csvtool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/csvtool/):

```
csvtool col 1 my-file.csv
```

See `csvtool --help` for details.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it with standard command-line utilities, either `cut` or `awk` would work

```
cut -d, -f1 yourfile
```

```
awk -F, '{print $1}' yourfile
```

You could also use `sed` to substitute everything after the first comma-delimited field with nothing

```
sed 's/,.*//' yourfile
```

The same substitution syntax would work in `vim` (since you tagged the question with that) i.e. after entering command mode with <kbd>Esc</kbd>

```
:1,$s/,.*//
```

Comment: Just for the hell of it, another option is to grep the first non-`,` characters with `grep -o '^[^,]*' yourfile`, but I agree that my first instinct is `cut` (then `awk`).